# Apache Ignite Cache

Tags: ignite

I have a client connected to two ignite servers in the cluster which acquires the lock on the object1 for the time specified (I acquired the lock for 15minutes on the object to test different scenarios), when we hit the server with the same request object on which there is a lock it should fail because the lock already exists on that object.

I have defined the cache on both the servers. I am testing the servers in the following order to check if the cache is shared among those servers if one of them is down.

- Server1 is up & Server2 is up then Lock acquired on transaction object
- server1 is down & Server2 is up then Failed (lock already present on object)
- Server1 is up & Server2 is up then Failed (lock already present on object)
- Server1 is up & Server2 is down then Success (acquired lock on object, as per my understanding this should have failed since the transaction is in process)

As per my understanding when the server1 is up and server2 is down the lock should be failed since it already exists, but it was a success.
Could you help me understand why the last case was a success and I would like to know how long does it take for the cache to be shared by both servers.

Comment: What is your success/failure criteria? Can you provide your test code and give more information about what you expect and what is not working?

Comment: I am testing it in the following scenario. I acquired the lock on the transaction (e.g. recharge) to avoid duplicate transactions on the account.
I did configure the cache on client and servers (both servers are connected in topology). I am trying to test if lock on the transaction is being shared between the servers by taking down one of the servers at a time.
While doing so I ran into a scenario where the cache was not shared. I ran the steps in same order I mentioned above to test if the cache is being shared between the servers when one of them is down.

Comment: I need to take a look at the code. Otherwise we will only confuse each other.